# How do I display and image from a data url in python?

Tags: python

I have an image that's encoded as a data url.

How do I display the original image from this in python?

Comment: what's a "data url"? ... and what do you mean by "display"?  Python is a programming language.  It doesn't have any way to display images on its own.

Comment: Data URLs are a Uniform Resource Identifier scheme that allow you to include data items inline in a web page as if they were being referenced as external resources. Data URLs are a form of Uniform Resource Locators, although they do not in fact remotely locate anything. Instead, the resource data is contained within the URL string itself as a base64-encoded string. This saves the browser from having to make additional HTTP requests for the external resources, and can thus increase page loading speed.

Comment: `print('<img src="%s">' % url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tkinter to open a window for viewing the image and urllib to read the image data e.g;

```
import io
import base64
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    from urllib.request import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()

image_url = "data:image/png;base64,iVB........"
image_byt = urlopen(image_url).read()
image_b64 = base64.encodestring(image_byt)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_b64)

cv = tk.Canvas(bg='white')
cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

cv.create_image(10, 10, image=photo, anchor='nw')
root.mainloop()
```